# Regex return string between two matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get the string between two specific matches, for example two hashtags.

What I would like to achieve:

> input: `some text in front ##hi there## some text behind`
>
> output:  `hi there`

With `/%%(.*)%%/`, `##hi there##` is returned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is the language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sorry, I didn't know that was relevant. It's PHP

Comment: Just access `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a look ahead and look behind.

```
(?<=##).*(?=##)
```

This will match `hi there`

https://regex101.com/r/qUR4NR/1

Comment: How about if I wanted multiple matches, say the string is `there %%are%% two %%matches%% now`